# HTTPS without WWW returns ERR_CONNECTED_REFUSED? (AWS)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, https, dns

I'm chasing my tail trying to track this one down. I'm curious if it's coming down to an issue with my elastic beanstalk configuration on AWS.

Currently, I have a domain setup that works fine when it's accessed by any of the following prefixes:

```
www.DOMAIN.com
http://DOMAIN.com
http://www.DOMAIN.com
https://www.DOMAIN.com
```

However, it does not work with the following prefix.

```
https://DOMAIN.com
```

When accessing the domain with just the https protocol prefixed, I'm receiving an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Chrome, and "Safari Can't Connect To Server" on Safari.

I've searched around on stack overflow and haven't been able to find a solution that's worked.

This domain is powered by elastic beanstalk on AWS.

Also, here's a copy of the .htaccess file used.

```
# -*- mode: apache -*-

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule .*$ app/index.php [L]
```

Any suggestions on where to look would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include a screenshot showing your Route53 records and security groups.

Comment: @tedder42 if www requests are getting through it isn't going to be a security group problem, and it is better to ask a specific question about how DNS is configured rather than asking for a screenshot (which could leak sensitive information)

Comment: @MichaelB I'm guessing the facts don't match- I wouldn't be surprised if "https www" doesn't work in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD (command prompt) Admin and RUN below command one by one.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew

netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
```

Now Restart your computer to get rid of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.